# Erase a hard drive without reinstalling Windows 8, by a Windows recovery disk?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, windows-8.1

Is there an option in a Windows 8 default recovery disk (a USB key in my case), to erase the main hard drive where Windows 8 is installed, *without Windows 8 being reinstalled afterwards*? Or to do this, is it necessary to use a third-party eraser program?

I would appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are different versions, but generally once booted from the recovery disc, select advanced options, then cmd (command) prompt. From there you can format the c: drive. That will wipe **THE WHOLE C: DRIVE PARTITION AND EVERYTHING ON IT**. You will then have an empty C: that doesn't boot (because there is nothing on it). This should leave any recovery partitions etc you have untouched.

**BEFORE YOU FORMAT C:**
You need to check it actually is your C drive, as drive letters can be moved when booting from other media.

You will probably be dropped into DOS, at the X:\ prompt. CD C:\ should get you to the C: drive. Use DIR to check if the files/folders are the ones you expect to be in the C: Drive.

Then use the Format command.

Format C:

That should work, but you have not said how you intend to use it moving forward, so that might not put the correct filesystem on for you.

If you don't understand most of what I have explained here, continue with EXTREME CAUTION.  There are no easy rollbacks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So there is no standalone GUI option, unlike "Refresh" or "Reset", and only through the command prompt?

Comment: @Patrick There isn't but you can proceed with a normal installation and at the point where you select where to install you have the option to delete all partitions or as many as you want if you want and then just cancel the installation process. The end result is the same.

Comment: As @ChanganAuto said you can go that way. But be careful not to delete the wrong partition (and less you have no interest in doing recovery or anything in the future, then delete them all), but this method might not format your drive, then you are back to a more complex version of formatting.

If you want a proper GUI then something like :
https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/usb-partition-manager.html

But you will need a working PC to create one.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Or any mainstream live Linux session by using GParted or Disks. If you actually want to clean up the drive then Gparted > Device menu > Create a new partition table (choose GPT for any modern computer; otherwise "MBR" for old, pre-2012, BIOS based machines) will blank it and make it as if it was new. Do not create any partitions, let the OS installer do it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; thank you for the further information!